# Using autofs to mount NFS shares when host is available

Tags: ubuntu, mount, backup, nfs, autofs

I have set up a NFS server on my NAS box, and I can mount the directory on by Ubuntu 20.04 desktop PC.

I have also set up autofs to mount the share, which also works. When I start autofs, the mount is mounted, and when I stop it, the mount is unmounted.

What I want to achieve is auto-mounting the share when the NAS box boots up (it is not always running), and unmount it (or display notification), when the NAS goes offline.

I also want to set up automatic backups (e.g. using "Back in Time"), so my idea is that when I power the NAS, the share is mounted & the backup software can start a backup according to schedule. Basically how MacOS is working.

Can this be done? If so, can anyone tell me how?

Comment: The idea of `autofs` is to mount when you access the share and unmount after a certain period of inactivity. You don't need to stop it. As for the detection, a cron task to check periodically if the host is up and, if it is, check the schedule (and already running backups).

Comment: Not sure if this will work out fine. I will have to check how Back in Time reacts when the mount is not accessible. Since it thinks its a local folder, it might just go ahead and create folders in the local (empty/un-mounted) mount point.

Also, I read somewhere that autofs features some sort of discovery, this is why I thought I could use it to mount as soon as the NAS becomes available.

Is there any other/better method for achieving my goals? (=> auto-mount NAS when online, backup runs when mount ready, but skips when not ready)

Comment: There are other ways. I use [BackupPC](https://backuppc.github.io/backuppc/) at some places and it is the server (your NAS) that contacts the client (you decide how, it could `ssh` for example). You can also run it on the client, with a script to check if the NAS is up, since backup jobs have hooks for scripts to run before and after the actual backup.